# OpenGL ES 2.0 loading dynamic textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, loading, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I have a view that needs to render multiple images at once, and i have a lot of textures to work with.
Problem is, the textures are changing because i cache a limited amount of images at any given time, so i need to load textures on the fly, which stalls the rendering quite heavily.
How do i go around this?

Comment: Are you using any type of compression?

Comment: I am loading the thumbnails through MediaStore in the 565 config if that's what you mean...
How do I use compression?

Answer (score 0):

The compression would actually hold you back as you would have to spend time performing the compression algorithm to get the image into a usable form.

How many textures are you working with and what size are they?

What you could try doing if the textures are small is cram several textures into one big texture and use texture coordinates to pick the right one. This would reduce how many times you would have to glGenTexture and glBindTexture. Also, if there is any sort of pattern to how your textures are accessed then you could leverage that to intelligently group your textures into a larger texture.

If you could provide additional information about the nature of your textures such as does their content change or anything else, then you might be able to get an even more helpful answer.

Comment: The textures are images from the SD card, about 500x500 pixels on average. They are presented in a grid of square images. They are loaded in order of importance by a seperate loading thread, then passed on to the GL thread for it to load into the GL context. I tried to group them into rows such that each row is a GL texture, but the problem is I need to draw the small bitmaps loaded from the media storage into the bitmap that holds the row texture, and since Canvas drawing is slow, I get drawn back on texture load times, and I also have to reload the row textures when new bitmaps into them.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, then for each row texture you need to overlay a smaller image (e.g thumbnail) from the media storage via Android's Canvas class? If this is the case why not have OpenGL draw the row texture followed by drawing the thumbnail on top of it. Then you have no need to go to the canvas class to mix the two textures together.